# How can I install the latest apt package for Cockpit with apt?

Tags: apt

I'm running 18.04TLS, and have Cockpit version 164-1.

If I go to https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/cockpit I see there's a new package 170-1, but I can't install it, because it is not Stable.

Is there any workaround to use these packages to install the new version?
I don't want to build it from source.

Comment: That version is in [backports](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-backports/cockpit), so enable backports and install it.

Comment: This new version is available to download from this site: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/amd64/cockpit/170-1~ubuntu18.04.1 but you must remember to download all required dependencies packages before you will try update it on you system.

Comment: I have enabled backports repository on my Ubuntu Bionic and at this moment `apt show cockpit` return package version 164-1.

Comment: @muru: backports is "install new software on old OS", not "install new software on new OS", so it's not a backport I think, it is a "pending review package"

Comment: @balint at this point, 18.04 is an old OS. Only those packages that need an SRU will ever see a major update without backports.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/151283/158442 on how that works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the explanation by @muru, it turned out, that Ubuntu freezes all software at the time of the release, so no updates on the main channel.

However, in 18.04 backports are enabled by default, so it is easy to install any further updates without any change to default apt settings:

```
 sudo apt install cockpit/bionic-backports
```